# Function not getting arguments

Tags: java, file, function, arguments

Maybe a silly question, but it's driving me mad.

I have a function (`readAudioDataFromFile`) that's not reciveing it's arguments when called from main. It doesn't throws any compiling error, exceptions or the like, it just returns wrong values.

Here some simplified code:

`Main` Class

```
package audioCheck;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class AudioCheck
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String filePath1 = "C:/file1.wav";
            String filePath2 = "C:/file2.wav";

        new readAudioDataFromFile(filePath1, filePath2);
    }

}
```

`ReadAudioDataFromFile` Class

```
package audioCheck;

import java.io.*;

public class readAudioDataFromFile {
    public readAudioDataFromFile(String filePath1, String filePath2) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // This is the part I hardcode for getting the correct results, instead of passing them as args.
// String filePath2 = "C:/file2.wav";
// String filePath1 = "C:/file1.wav";

         FileInputStream ins2 = null;
         FileInputStream ins1 = null;

         File file2 = new File(filePath2);
         File file1 = new File(filePath2);

         int size2 = (int) file2.length();    
         int size1 = (int) file1.length();

         byte [] buffer2=new byte [size2];
         byte [] buffer1=new byte [size1];

         try {
               ins2= new FileInputStream(filePath2);
               ins1= new FileInputStream(filePath1);

         } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
         try {
             //contar e imprimir buffer 2
               ins2.read(buffer2, 0,size2);
               int count2 =0;
               for(int i=0; i<buffer2.length; i++)
               {
                 if(buffer2[i]!=0)
                   count2++;
               }
               String data2 = String.valueOf((count2)); 
               System.out.println(data2);

               //contar e imprimir buffer1
               ins1.read(buffer1, 0,size1);
               int count1 =0;
               for(int i=0; i<buffer1.length; i++)
               {
                 if(buffer1[i]!=0)
                   count1++;
               }
               String data1 = String.valueOf((count1)); 
               System.out.println(data1);

         } 
         catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }

}
```

The thing is that when I hardcode the file paths on `readAudioDataFromFile`, it works perfectly. Here are the outputs for each case.

Tryign to pass args from `main`:

```
348
388
```

Hardcoding `readAudioDataFromFile`:

```
1205739
1346847
```

Thank you in advice

Comment: What values are you hardcoding?

Comment: Are you saying it works as shown, but not when you pass args from main -- something you didn't show?

Comment: You are calling constructor not method

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It works when i hardcode the file paths on the calss directly instead of doign it on main. `String filePath1 = "C:/file1.wav";            String filePath2 = "C:/file2.wav";`. @ppeterka 66, in fact, I'm starting to learn, sorry

Comment: How are you doing the alternative? Show us.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis edited the question and added the hardcoded part commented on `readAudioDataFromFile`

Comment: @GonzaloAcosta That cannot happen. Try adding a `System.out.println(filePath2)` to see what your arguments are.

Comment: You're hardcoding different paths - `file1.wav` vs `estrella.wav` etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet already corrected that

Comment: So what does it print?